# Antipode of a Hopf algebra being an antihomomorphism: unable to follow the proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

A PhD [thesis](https://ntnuopen.ntnu.no/ntnu-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/3032313/Adrian%20de%20Jesus%20Celestino%20Rodriguez_PhD.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) contains the following proof that antipode of a Hopf algebra is algebra antihomomorphism (page 22):
[image: Proof]
Here $\nu = \eta \circ \varepsilon$, where $\eta$ is the unit map and $\varepsilon$ is the counit map, 2.1.4 refers to
$$\nu(h)=\sum h_{1}S(h_2)=\sum S(h_1) h_2 \ \ \ \ (2.1.4)$$
by definition of the antipode as the convolutional inverse of $\text{id}_{H}$, Sweedler notation for comultiplication $\Delta$
$$\Delta h = \sum h_{1}\otimes h_{2}$$
is used, 2.1.5 refers to
$$h = (\text{id} * \nu) h = \sum h_{1}\nu(h_{2}) \ \ \ \ (2.1.5)$$
which follows from the fact that $\nu$ is the identity in the convolution algebra of $\text{End}(H)$, 2.1.6 refers to
$$S(h)=\sum S(h_{1})\nu(h_{2}) \ \ \ \ (2.1.6)$$
and 2.1.7 is
$$\nu(hl)=\nu(h)\nu(l) \ \ \ \ (2.1.7)$$
The notation $v(h)$ is not used in the text above, at least I wasn't able to find any definition for it. I assumed it is a typo, and $\nu(h)=v(h)$. Even so, I wasn't able to follow through the second line. The author seems to denote repeated summation through a single sum sign, and assume that
$$\nu(h_2)=\sum h_{2}S(h_3)$$
but this is not true, the correct way to write this down should be
$$\sum (h_{2})_{1} S((h_2)_2)$$
and if you redefine $h_{2}$ as $(h_{2})_{1}$, you can't use it later as a synonym for the old $h_{2}$. Also it is not clear how $S((hl)_{1})$ becomes $S(h_{1}l_{1})$, and how the second summation is dealt with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the few tricks of the trade:

By coassociativity we have
$$(id\otimes\Delta)(\Delta(h)) = (\Delta\otimes id)(\Delta(h))=:\sum h_1\otimes h_2\otimes h_3\qquad(*)$$
(more generally: if you use $\Delta$ several (say $k-1$) times, you will always get the same result, which is *denoted* by $\sum h_1\otimes h_2\otimes\dots\otimes h_k$).
We can rewrite $(*)$, using $\Delta(h) = \sum h_1\otimes h_2$, as
$$\sum \Delta(h_1)\otimes h_2 = \sum h_1\otimes \Delta(h_2) = \sum h_1\otimes h_2\otimes h_3.$$
This hopefully settles your first problem.

As for your 2nd problem, why $(hl)_1=h_1l_1$ - I would say that the notation in the proof got a bit unclear, but it refers to the compatibility of the product and of the coproduct, which is in Sweedler's notation
$$\sum(hl)_1\otimes(hl)_2 = \sum h_1\,l_1\otimes h_2\,l_2$$

Comment: It is not entirely clear, what happens to the multipliers then we perform $\sum h_{1} \otimes \Delta (h_{2})=\sum h_{1}\otimes h_{2} \otimes h_{3}$: what happens to $\nu(h_{2})$ when we have $\sum h_{1} \otimes \nu(h_{2})h_{2} ?$

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku $\sum \nu(h_1) h_2\otimes h_3 = \sum h_1\otimes \nu(h_2)h_3 = \sum h_1\otimes h_2\nu(h_3) = \sum h_1\otimes h_2$ (a thing that might cause confusion is that it's "not the same $h_1$ and $h_2$" in the last sum as in the previous sums